# Message: Trying to get property of non-object in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code in my Model page:

```
 public function getAll($researcherpk){
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('research');
 $this->db->join('researcher', 'researcher = lastname');
 $this->db->where('researcherpk', $researcherpk); 
 return $this->db->get()->row_array();
```

But when I use it on my View Page

```
Age: <?php echo $data['age'];?>        // this work

<?php   foreach ($data as $v){ ?>          //this has an error

  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $v->title?></td>
      <td><?php echo $v->track_records?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

I get the error:

```
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
```

In my Controller page:

```
 public function researcher($researcherpk){

 $this->load->model('ResearchModel');

 $result['data'] = $this->ResearchModel->getAll($researcherpk);
 $this->load->view('researcher',$result);

 }
```

What do you think is the problem here? What is my alternative solution for it or changes?

Comment: Sorry, but how could i do this var_dump($data);?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out was wrong! Check my answer :)

Answer (score 10):

Change your return to:

```
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Then try using `$v['title']` and `$v['track_records']`

```
<?php foreach ($data as $v): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $v['title']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $v['track_records']?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Look at [the codeigniter docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) to learn more.

`result_array()`:

> This function returns the query result as a pure array

That is what you want.

You are mixing it with:

`row_array()`:

> This function returns a single result row. If your query has more than one row, it returns only the first row.

This is not what you want.

Comment: `$data` is not a multidimensional array.

Comment: Thank you, I just looked more into it. I'll edit my answer @RocketHazmat

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `row_array` this means `$data` is an *array* of a single row.  `$data['age']` works, because `age` is a field in the row.

You can `foreach($data as $v)`, but this will only loop over the *fields* in that particular row.

You can just do `echo $data['title']`.   `$data` is not a multidimensional array.

If you want multiple rows, then use `return $this->db->get()->result_array();`.  Then you can loop over the rows:

```
foreach ($data as $v){
    echo $v['age'];
    echo $v['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an array not an object so:

Change this:

```
  <td><?php echo $v->title?></td>
  <td><?php echo $v->track_records?></td>
```

To this:

```
  <td><?php echo $v['title']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $v['track_records']; ?></td>
```